# How can I get a character in a position of the screen with ncurses in C?

Tags: c, ncurses, game-development

I'm learning ncurses in C, and I have this question because it would simplify a hobby of mine.
Or what libraries can be used (also in combination with curses) to get from a certain position of the screen its character?

Answer (score 2):

You can find out what character is currently displayed at a certain position on the screen with the [`mvinch()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcurses/inch.html), e.g.:

```
at_topleft = mvinch(0, 0);
```

Comment: Really thanks. Is there a method to move an area of the screen from a position to another or I have to write a function doing it?